# Can't edit the overflow-x:hidden

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have this html div:

```
<div style="top: 363px; overflow-x: hidden; width: 1350px;" id="container"></div>
```

I can't find where that div is located I want to overwrite the overflow-x: hidden maybe delete or set it to auto.

What I did was:

```
#container {
    min-height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: auto; 
}
```

This won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying that you cannot edit the html? If that's true, then you can add an `!important` statement to the css:

```
#container {
    min-height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: auto !important; 
}
```

This will override the styles.

Comment: @user3871110 Don't worry, it's fine! By the way, you can accept this answer by clicking the check mark to the left! (: